# Rewriting data in logs with log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

This is my logger.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <logger>
      <path>C:\</path>
      <file>dd-MM-yyyy'.log'</file>
      <levels>
        <add>ERROR</add>
        <add>INFO</add>
      </levels>
      <pattern>{level}|{date}|{method_guid}|{method_name}|{description}|{status}|{msg}|{inout}|{param0}</pattern>
      <dateFormat>MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss.fff</dateFormat>
      <reloadEveryMinutes>1</reloadEveryMinutes>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maxSize>1MB</maxSize>
    </logger>
```

Here I set add settings for logger.
     var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            hierarchy.Configured = false;

```
        hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

        var patternLayout = new PatternLayout() { ConversionPattern = "%m%n" }; //%m - message, %n - new line
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        var roller = new RollingFileAppender
        {
            AppendToFile = true,
            StaticLogFileName = false,
            File = config.Path,
            DatePattern = config.FileName,
            PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true,
            Layout = patternLayout,
            MaxSizeRollBackups = 10000,
            MaximumFileSize = "10000",
            RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite,
            CountDirection = 0

        };
        roller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

And log4net generate files with such name 15-05-2017. When the size of file will more 1MB it creates new file 15-05-2017.1 and put old data to it and write new data to 15-05-2017.

What should I do that it writes new data in 15-05-2017.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change CountDirection to -1 (this is default value) according to documentation,
 see [CountDirection](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_CountDirection.htm)

Comment: When I use CountDirection = -1 then 15-05-2017 is newer than 15-05-2017.1. 15-05-2017.1 is newer than 15-05-2017.2. I need a vice versa